# How to create a loop or function for the logic for this list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
CustomerID  EventID EventType   EventTime
6           1        Facebook    42373.31586
6           2        Facebook    42373.316
6           3        Web         42374.32921
6           4        Twitter     42377.14913
6           5        Facebook    42377.40598
6           6        Web         42378.31245
```

- CustomerID:  the unique identifier associated with the particular
  customer
- EventID:  a unique identifier about a particular online activity
- EventType:  the type of online activity associated with this record
  (Web, Facebook, or Twitter)
- EventTime:  the date and time at which this online activity took
  place. This value is measured as the number of days since January 1, 1900, with fractions indicating particular times of day.  So for example, an event taking place at the stroke of midnight on January 1, 2016 would be have an EventTime of 42370.00 while an event taking place at noon on January 1, 2016 would have an EventTime of 42370.50.

I've managed to import the CSV and creating into a list with the following code:

```
# Import Libraries & Set working directory
import csv

# STEP 1:  READING THE DATA INTO A PYTHON LIST OF LISTS
f = open('test1000.csv', "r") # Import CSV as file type
a = f.read() # Convert file type into string
split_list = a.split("\r") # Removes \r
split_list[0:5] # Viewing the list

# Convert from lists to 'list of lists'
final_list = []
for row in split_list:
    split_list = row.split(',') # Split list by comma delimiter
    final_list.append(split_list) 
print(final_list[0:5])

#CREATING INITIAL BLANK LISTS FOR OUTPUTTING DATA
legit = [] 
fraud = []
```

What I need to do next is sort each record into the fraud or legit list of lists. A record would be considered fraudulent under the following parameters. As such, that record would go to the fraud list.

**Logic to assign a row to the fraud list**: The CustomerID performs the same EventType within the last 4 hours.

For example, row 2 (event 2) in the sample data set above, would be moved to the fraud list because event 1 happened within the last 4 hours. On the other hand, event 4 would go to the legit list because in there are no Twitter records that happened in the last 4 hours.

The data set is in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

This solution groups by `CustomerID` and `EventType` and then checks if the previous event time occurred less than (`lt`) 4 hours ago (`4. / 24`).

```
df['possible_fraud'] = (
    df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'EventType'])
      .EventTime
      .transform(lambda group: group - group.shift())
      .lt(4. / 24))

>>> df
   CustomerID  EventID EventType    EventTime possible_fraud
0           6        1  Facebook  42373.31586          False
1           6        2  Facebook  42373.31600           True
2           6        3       Web  42374.32921          False
3           6        4   Twitter  42377.14913          False
4           6        5  Facebook  42377.40598          False
5           6        6       Web  42378.31245          False

>>> df[df.possible_fraud]
   CustomerID  EventID EventType  EventTime possible_fraud
1           6        2  Facebook  42373.316           True
```

Comment: Having trouble testing. Can I see the full code you used? Gettng the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: `df` generally means a pandas DataFrame.  I simply copied your table at the top of the post with `df = pd.read_clipboard()`. Yuo may want to try `pd.read_csv(filename)`

Comment: Thank you for that. Sorry to still be a bother now gettinganother error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: That's the same error. You should have a data frame, not a list.

Comment: Much appreciated. All squared with that now. I don't think its catching all them. I ran this on a sample of 100 rows then visually checked a few and there were a lot missing.  [sampledata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4r91k2h9qbydyr/test1000.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @ChrisStroud the difference might come from the fact that your dataset is not really sorted by time. 

`df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').sort_values('EventTime')`

instead of simple read_csv makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, pandas based solution seems more smart, but here is an example of using just inserted dictionary.

PS Try to perform input and output by himself

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

sample ="""
6           1        Facebook    42373.31586
6           2        Facebook    42373.316
6           3        Web         42374.32921
6           4        Twitter     42377.14913
5           5        Web         42377.3541
6           6        Facebook    42377.40598
6           7        Web         42378.31245
"""

last = {} # This dict will contain recent time 
#values of events by client ID, for ex.: 
#{"6": {"Facebook": 42373.31586, "Web": 42374.32921}}

legit = []
fraud = []

for row in sample.split('\n')[1:-1:]:
    Cid, Eid, Type, Time = row.split()
    if Cid not in last.keys():
        legit.append(row)
        last[Cid] = {Type: Time}    
        row += '\tlegit'
    else:   
        if Type not in last[Cid].keys():
            legit.append(row)
            last[Cid][Type] = Time
            row += '\tlegit'
        else:
            if float(Time) - float(last[Cid][Type]) > (4. / 24):
                legit.append(row)
                last[Cid][Type] = Time
                row += '\tlegit'
            else:
                fraud.append(row)
                row += '\tfraud'
    print row
```